# How to pass a php variable to a fancybox form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my page I have a lot of divs that contain info about products. These product divs are constructed by data got from mySQL. When a user wants more info about a product, it clicks on the one that wants and a fancybox form pops out, ready to fill his details and on submit we will get them by email.

The `#xam` div is actually the form with textboxes mostly. My question is how can I pass let's say the `$row['title']` of the selected product to a hidden textbox in the fancybox form?

**here is the jquery that opens the fancybox**

```
    $(".modalbox").fancybox({
    'closeBtn' : false
    });
```

**here is how I trigger the form to show**

```
<a class="modalbox" href="#xam">
<div>
a small div that contains few info about a product that when it's clicked it opens the #xam div where a user can put his email to get more info from us
</div>
</a>
```

**here is the form tha opens when the user click on the "email us" link by a fancybox**

```
UPDATE. this is the code of xam



<div id="xam">
    <div id="reservation-form" class="block">
        <div class="block-inner white block-shadow">
            <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
                <label for="phone">Phone<span class="required"></span></label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" type="text" value="" size="30">
            <button id="send">send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just `echo $row['title']` wherever the value is supposed to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the product's data inside html data-attribute. For example :

```
<div id="products">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($products as $row) : ?>
        <li>
            <div data-title="<?=$row['title'];?>" data-id="<?=$row['id'];?>" data-etc="">
                This is product <?=$row['title'];?>
                <a class="action-xam">Click me</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now in javascript, you can access those data-info with jQuery using this line

```
var title = $(this).data("title"); //This being the selected product
```

This means you can do something like this :

```
$(".action-xam").click(function(){
    var title = $(this).prev("div").data("title"); //This being the selected product
    //Do something with title, like putting it inside #xam
    //$("#xam something").text(title);
});
```

Note that you can put the data-attribute anywhere, even in the `<a>Click me</a>` where the user clicks.

**EDIT**

When the user clicks on a product :

```
$(".action-xam").click(function(){
    //Get some info like the title
    var title = $(this).prev("div").data("title");
    //Insert the info into xam
    $("#xam-product-title").val(title);
});
```

And you need xam to have a hidden input

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
    <label for="phone">Phone<span class="required"></span></label>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" type="text" value="" size="30">

    <input id="xam-product-title" value="" name="product-title" type="hidden">

    <button id="send">send</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT 2**

Add to the class `action-xam` to all your `<a class="modalbox action-xam" href="#xam">` and put this :

```
$(".action-xam").click(function(){
    //Get some info like the title
    var title = $(this).next("div").data("title");  //Prev or next, try to get the data-attribute with some jQuery. Should be easy with console.log
    //Insert the info into xam
    $("#xam-product-title").val(title);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am trying it but find it kind of hard to implement it in my actual jQuery that loads the #xam form `$(".modalbox").fancybox({
    'closeBtn' : false
    });`

Comment: Give more html code (the inside of the xam, and the javascript that opens the xam), so I can try to implement it. Or do a jsfiddle.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, what is your problem exactly ? Starting to get confused here. The user clicks on a product that triggers the modalbox. And when the user clicks on the modalbox, it triggers the xam ? Your question is how to pass the value from the product to the xam ?

Comment: In my page there are a lot of divs that contain info from the database like the title of the product, manufacturer and so on. The user may click on one and then a fancybox form pops out ( #xam ) and it is ready to type his phone number and press submit. My problem is that in my email I am not able to know what product he selected. So a workaround would be to pass the product tile to a hidden textbox in the form

Comment: The fancybox (modalbox) contains the #xam as inline

Comment: Edited the answer. (Fancybox has nothing to do with the problem, don't mind it)

Comment: Look, thank you for your help But as i said, the form is shown INSIDE the popup fancybox that it triggers when i click on `<a class="modalbox" href="#xam">` The #xam is not shown in the page as it has a display none. I do not know how to explain it in different words.

Comment: Ok I looked at how fancybox works. I don't see any problem. The form is hidden at first but when fancybox opens it, the form is displayed. So where is your problem ? You don't need xam to be displayed to modify it. 
See EDIT 2.